# Fetching SQL data via PHP script: connection doesn't seem to work, but no errors, if statements treat variable as not false

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am tearing my hair out on this, so to this site I go.

I have a PHP script. It's trying to access a MySQL database on the same server the script's on, using the very common mysql_connect (making a persistent connection) and assigning the result to the variable $user_con.

```
$user_con = mysql_connect([servername], [username], [password], TRUE);
//And no, that's not what's actually in the code, but I'm not going to give those
details up. :)
```

But for some reason, all attempts to actually get data from it fail...without any errors. mysql_error(), both directly after the connection attempt and after using mysql_select_db(), outputs nothing. The if statements are treating $user_con as not-empty (if mysql_connect fails, it outputs FALSE, which is considered empty using empty()), despite the fact that echoing $user_con outputs nothing. The script itself doesn't crash, and outputs the rest of the HTML and the data from the other SQL connection I have going just fine.

For some reason, the script only notices that the connection is not working far later on in execution. When I try to fetch the data, I have it check to see if the connection exists, and it finally acts like it doesn't have it, so I get it to try to reconnect and that fails, as indicated by the next if block I have where it outputs different data if it can't fetch the stuff from the database.

```
if(empty($user_con))
{
     $check = mysql_ping($user_con);
     if(!$check)
     {
           $user_con = mysql_connect([servername], [username], [password], TRUE);
           if(!empty($user_con))
           {
               mysql_select_db("user_db", $user_con); 
           }
     }
 }

 if(empty($user_con))
 {
     $output .= "<br /><span class=\"comuser\">Posted by: User #" . $userid . "</span></p>";
     //Where $userid is outputted instead of the username I want to get from the database USING the userid
 }
```

I would also like to note that echoing a mysql_error() call anywhere within this code also outputs nothing, because that would be too easy, apparently.

On the page right now, as can be seen [here](http://volunteer.cs.und.edu/wildlife/interesting_videos.php), everything works fine except for the fact that the script just outputs userids instead of usernames.

I just can't figure out why I can't get this connection to work...even using my boss's code that he wrote to rectify this problem in other scripts doesn't work here (and in fact, actually causes a nice crash instead)!

Answer (score 0):

mysql_error() returns actual errors from the server while running a query. You're not getting that far.

In this case, it looks like your PHP errors are not displaying so you aren't seeing the connection error. Check your php.ini and your error.log.

Also, please use PDO or at least mysqli, and proper exception handling.